# Calculating a limit with series

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

Good evening to everyone. I have a limit that gave me a lot of trouble and I couldn't find a way to solve it. I tried solving it with series but I couldn't arrive at a result.
$$
\lim _{x\to 0+}\left(\frac{\left(e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\cos \left(\log _e\left(x\right)\right)+\cos \left(\arctan \left(x\right)\right)-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\right)}{\log _e\left(1+x^2\right)-\sin \left(x^2\right)}\right)
$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***tl;dr:*** This is going to be such a hoot.

- Let us start with the denominator:
  $$\begin{align}
  \ln\left(1+x^2\right)-\sin \left(x^2\right)
  &= 
  x^2-\frac{x^4}{2} + o(x^4) - (x^2+o(x^4)) = -\frac{x^4}{2} + o(x^4)
  \end{align}
  $$
- Now, the meat — the numerator, piece by piece:

  - No Taylor for the first, it does not apply (the arguments do not tend to $0$, for a start).
    $$\begin{align}
    \lvert e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\cos \left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)\rvert \leq 
    e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{} 0
    \end{align}
    $$
    and this term is negligible in front of any power of $x$: it decays exponentially. So in particular it is $o(x^4)$, say. *(Tell me if you need a proof of that. **Edit:** see $(\dagger)$ at the end)*
  - The second, we can do a series expansion:
    $$\begin{align}
    \cos \left(\arctan \left(x\right)\right)
    &= \cos\left( x- \frac{x^3}{3} + o(x^4)\right)= 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3x^4}{8} + o(x^4)
    \end{align}
    $$
    and the last term (series can be used as well):
    $$\begin{align}
    -e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} &= -(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4)) = -1+ \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4)
    \end{align}
    $$
    so overall
    $$\begin{align}
    e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\cos \left(\ln\left(x\right)\right) +\cos \left(\arctan \left(x\right)\right)-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} 
    &= o(x^4) + 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{3x^4}{8} + o(x^4)  + -1+ \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+o(x^4)\\
    &= \frac{x^4}{4}+o(x^4)
    \end{align}
    $$
- Putting it all together:
  $$
  \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\cos \left(\log _e\left(x\right)\right)+\cos \left(\arctan \left(x\right)\right)-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\log _e\left(1+x^2\right)-\sin \left(x^2\right)}
  = \frac{\frac{x^4}{4}+o(x^4)}{-\frac{x^4}{2} + o(x^4)}
  \xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{} -\frac{1}{2}.
  $$

---

**Edit:**

$(\dagger)$ We used the fact that, for any fixed $\alpha\geq 0$, 
$$
e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} = o(x^\alpha)
$$
when $x\to 0$. Note that setting $u=\frac{1}{x^2}$, this is equivalent to proving that for every $\alpha \geq 0$
$
e^{-u} = o(u^{-\alpha})
$ when $u\to+\infty$, or, again, equivalently, that $$\lim_{u\to+\infty}u^\alpha e^{-u} = 0$$ for any fixed $\alpha \geq 0$. Do you see why this is true?

Comment: +$1$: Good answer and explanation. :)

Comment: Why did you choose for the first term in the numerator(the one which decays to 0) to be equal to $o(x^4)$. How could you arrive to that term?

Comment: Actually, i chose it after all others. It is o (x^a) for any a, but after looking at the others a=4 is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! Btw what theorem you've used to conclude that for a term which decays to zero it is equal to o(x^n)... because I can't remember to have found such theorem in my math book,

Comment: Will elaborate on that in 5mn.

Comment: Do you mean you'll answer my question in 5 minutes? Ok then

Comment: @T4yl0r Done, see my edit at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understood perfectly!:)

Comment: @T4yl0r You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without relying on Taylor series, note that

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left({e^{-{1\over x^2}}\cos(\ln x)+\cos(\arctan x)-e^{-{x^2\over2}}\over\ln(1+x^2)-\sin(x^2)}\right)
={\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\left({e^{-{1\over x^2}}\cos(\ln x)\over x^4}\right)+\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\cos(\arctan x)-e^{-{x^2\over2}}\over x^4\right)\over\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\ln(1+x^2)-\sin(x^2)\over x^4 \right)}$$

provided all three limits on the right exist and the one in the denominator is nonzero. (The "cleverness" here, if any, is knowing to use an $x^4$.  But that really just comes from anticipating what's going to happen in the denominator.)

Let's take them one at a time, starting with the denominator. A change of variable and two L'Hopitals lead to

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\ln(1+x^2)-\sin(x^2)\over x^4 \right)=\lim_{u\to0^+}\left(\ln(1+u)-\sin(u)\over u^2 \right)=\lim_{u\to0^+}\left({1\over1+u}-\cos u\over2u \right)=\lim_{u\to0^+}\left({-1\over(1+u)^2}+\sin u\over2 \right)=-{1\over2}$$

As for the first limit in the numerator,

$$\left|\lim_{x\to0^+}\left({e^{-{1\over x^2}}\cos(\ln x)\over x^4}\right)\right|\le\lim_{x\to0^+}\left({e^{-{1\over x^2}}\over x^4}\right)=\lim_{u\to\infty}{u^2\over e^u}=\lim_{u\to\infty}{2u\over e^u}=\lim_{u\to\infty}{2\over e^u}=0$$

Finally, it's convenient to convert

$$\cos(\arctan x)={1\over\sec(\arctan x)}={1\over\sqrt{1+\tan^2(\arctan x)}}={1\over\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

so that, as with the limit in the denominator, we get

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(\cos(\arctan x)-e^{-{x^2\over2}}\over x^4\right)=\lim_{u\to0^+}\left((1+u)^{-1/2}-e^{-u/2}\over u^2 \right)=\lim_{u\to0^+}\left(-{1\over2}(1+u)^{-3/2}+{1\over2}e^{-u/2}\over 2u \right)=\lim_{u\to0^+}\left({3\over4}(1+u)^{-5/2}-{1\over4}e^{-u/2}\over 2 \right)={1\over4}$$

Putting it all together, we get

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left({e^{-{1\over x^2}}\cos(\ln x)+\cos(\arctan x)-e^{-{x^2\over2}}\over\ln(1+x^2)-\sin(x^2)}\right)={0+{1\over4}\over-{1\over2}}=-{1\over2}$$